# (MVC) I have a search bar in my shared _Layout. It works from other Views but not in the _Layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Basically what the title says. I have a view named books in which the search bar works perfectly and gives results. This is not happening in the _Layout shared view. I've tried several scripts and stuff but to no avail. Any advice?

This is the _Layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

@model IEnumerable<GoodReads.Models.Libro>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Nombre de aplicación", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Inicio", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Registrar Turno", "AltaTurno", "Turno")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Buscar Libros", "Books", "Libro")</li>
                    <li>
                        @using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Get))
                        {
                        <div>
                            @Html.TextBox("parametro")
                            <input type="submit" id="btnSearch" value="Some text"/>                                
                        </div>                               
                        }
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Books">
        
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer></footer>
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

This is the Books view

```
@model IEnumerable<GoodReads.Models.Libro>
@{
      /**/
      ViewBag.Title = "Books";
}

<head>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Style.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div style="margin-left: 350px; margin-top: 50px;">
            <h1 class="title-font">
                @item.Title &nbsp;
                <small class="year-font">(@item.Year)</small>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left: 350px; margin-top: 10px;">
            <p style="font-size: 22px;">by @item.Author</p>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left: 350px; margin-top: 10px;">
            <p style="font-size: 22px;">@item.ISBN</p>
        </div>
    }
</body>
```

The Controller for Books (The conection to the database is made through instead of doing it directly in the controller)

```
    // GET: Libro
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }  

    public ActionResult Books(string parametro)
    {
        List<Libro> listalibros = ADLibros.BuscarLibro(parametro);
        return View(listalibros);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your form.  You don't set its action.  If you don't tell it it will use the default which is the controller that renders the page.  So when your Books controller renders the page this works because the default controller will be the books controller.  You need to specify the action of your get form explicitly.  To see the problem use your browser developer tools to inspect the form for the books page and the other pages.

To fix (assuming your controller for books is called `BooksController`) change the form code in your _Layout page to this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("books", "books", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div>
        @Html.TextBox("parametro")
        <input type="submit" id="btnSearch" value="Some text" />
    </div>
}
```

We are using an overload of `Html.BeginForm` with 3 arguments.  The first is the `actionName`, the second is the `controllerName` and the 3rd is the `FormMethod`.